# Better aliases in eshell

Tags: eshell

I'm trying to translate some useful aliases from `zsh` to `eshell` (because `ansi-term` sucks).

This is one such alias: `alias l "ls -lAh $*"`

I want this to be able to receive any number of arguments (because ls can handle any number of args) but I still want this to work without arguments.
Now when I type `l` in `eshell` the `$*` expands to `null` and `ls -lAh null` is not a valid command.

I *could* write wrappers for some of my frequently-used shell commands, but isn't there any better way to do this?

Doesn't `eshell` have a mechanic for simple substitution instead of aliases behaving like lisp functions?

If this is the only way to do things in `eshell`, Is there *any* way to make `$*` expand to whitespace when it's empty or something?

Comment: I think you just used the wrong sort of quotes: `alias l 'ls -lAh $*'` behaves correctly with zero or more arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found something that helped me.

EmacsWiki says to do this: `alias | sed -E "s/^alias ([^=]+)='(.*)'$/alias \1 \2 \$*/g; s/'\\\''/'/g;" >~/.emacs.d/eshell/alias`
The above line is for `bash` (and the location of the alias file is wrong).

For `zsh` something like this should work:
`alias | sed -E "s/^([^=]+)='(.*)'$/alias \1 \2 \$*/g; s/'\\\''/'/g;" >~/.emacs.d/.cache/eshell/alias`

And then modify a few aliases by hand to fit `eshell`'s format (this doesn't take care of aliases that don't follow the format `<alias>='command'` and I lack the regex-fu knowledge to fix it, basically I need to replace the the parts that search for *only* single-quotes to allow unquoted words too, or you could make sure your aliases are all in the format I described above).

I don't know what I was doing wrong before but this works!

Comment: I'd like to offer what I think is a simpler sed expression. If I'm reading that correctly it looks like it is simply removing the `=` sign (for bash, and also prepending the word `alias` for zsh) ... for bash, the following works for me: `alias | sed -e 's/=/ /' >> ~/.emacs.d/eshell/bash_alias` for zsh is is only slightly more complex (unless I'm missing something about how zsh may emit oddly formed aliases): `alias | sed -r -e 's/^([^=]+)=/alias \1 /' >> ~/.emacs.d/eshell/zsh_alias`